# Regular expression for exact price in a string

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for checking if there is an exact price in a string.

The regex I had created that worked for the exact situation was

`.*?0,00`

As I am trying to capture when a price is exactly EUR 0,00.

But I am running into issues with prices like EUR 60,00, etc, as it is still matching the 0.00.

How would I create a regular expression to match exactly 0,00?

Comment: Try using [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b0,00\b` https://regex101.com/r/MBVJT4/1

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Why the "nsregularexpression" tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern `.*?0,00` does not contain boundaries and will match any char except a newline 0+ times non greedy followed by matching 0,00

You could make use of [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`

```
\b0,00\b
```

Or if a negative lookahead and lookbehind is supported, you could assert what is on the left and on the right is not a non whitespace char `\S` to not get a partial match in  `,0,00,`

```
(?<!\S)0,00(?!\S)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookarounds to assert that the character preceding `0,00` is not a digit, and the character following `0,00` is not a digit.

`(?<!\d)0,00(?!\d)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cfqIeR/1/)